# How to add a newline to run in C# and OpenXML with justified text using bookmarks

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a Word template with bookmarks that I populate during runtime. The whole template text is already set to justified. If I only insert one piece of text at bookmark then it's OK but now I'm facing a problem where one bookmark can potentially contain multiple lines with line breaks between them. The code that works for one piece of text is here:

```
foreach (BookmarkStart bookMarkStart in doc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
{
    if (bookMarkStart.Name == "Author")
    {
        var id = bookMarkStart.Id.Value;
        var bookmarkEnd = bookMarkEnds.Where(i => i.Id.Value == id).First();
        var runElement = new Run(new Text(author));
        bookmarkEnd.Parent.InsertAfter(runElement, bookmarkEnd);
    }
}
```

I have tried many things so far and the closest I've came was to append a break to the run and add new text after it. However, the problem I have is that the previous line is justified in a way that text is stretched over the whole line - e.g. if only two words are present then one is justified to the left side of the doc and the second one to the right. If I append multiple text lines then only the last one is correct.

I add multiple lines like this:

```
var id = bookMarkStart.Id.Value;
var bookmarkEnd = bookMarkEnds.Where(i => i.Id.Value == id).First();
var runElement = new Run();
runElement.Append(new Text(text1));
runElement.Append(new Break());
runElement.Append(new Text(text2));
bookmarkEnd.Parent.InsertAfter(runElement, bookmarkEnd);
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after posting the question here. The approach I used was to use paragraphs. In short, I built multiple paragraphs, one for each line, and added them to the bookmark as needed. Here's the sample code:

```
ParagraphProperties pProp = new ParagraphProperties();
Justification just = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Both };
pProp.Append(just);
var run = new Run(new Text(slText));
var para = new Paragraph();
para.Append(pProp);
para.Append(run);
bookmark.Parent.InsertAfterSelf(para);
```

The above code can be repeated multiple times and paragraph(s) added after the bookmark.